# ActiveAdmin makes submission blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Good time, overflowers!
I have an issue with the ActiveAdmin post submissiom.
Here, below is the code from app/admin/posts.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  index do
    column :title
    column :slug
    column :blurb
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :title
      f.input :slug
      f.input :blurb
      f.input :category
      f.input :content, :as => :text
    end
    f.inputs 'Images' do
      f.input :image, :label => 'Post image', :as => :file
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

And app/models/post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I don't know why, but somehow when i'm trying to submit post using ActiveAdmin
the result is something like this:

```
Post Details
Id  9
Title   Empty
Slug    Empty 
Blurb   Empty
Content     Empty
Category    Empty
Created At  August 31, 2014 11:00
Updated At  August 31, 2014 11:00
Image   Empty
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you for your time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Rails 4, you have to permit the params: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters

You can see in the log/development.log file which attributes is unpermitted.

Comment: it isn't very clear for me, how to permit strong params. I tried to use the following at app/admin/posts.rb: ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :title, :slug, :blurb

Comment: Eventually did you manage to save the values with permit_params?